# Django model doesn't relate itself to User through ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

my question is about modelforms, models and instances. After doing some troubleshooting I think my problem is that either the user field from UserFile doesn't associate itself to the auth.User or that the modelform doesn't pass the instance of auth.User. The error is at the dynamic pathing - file_destination - when I try self.user it can't find the user :/

```
# Model

class UserFile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='user_file', primary_key=True, unique=True)
    user_file = models.FileField(upload_to=file_destination, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user_file.name

# View 

def login_index(request):
    template = 'loginIndex.html'
    context = Context()
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UserUpload(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user)
            context.update({'form': form})
            if form.is_valid() and form.is_multipart():
                instance = UserFile(user_file=request.FILES.get('user_file'))
                instance.save()     
        else:
            form = UserUpload()
            context.update({'form': form})
        return render(request, template, context)

    else:
        return render(request, template, context)

# Form

class UserUpload(ModelForm):
    user_file = forms.FileField(required=False, widget=forms.ClearableFileInput, label='Upload')

    class Meta:
        model = UserFile
        fields = ['user_file']

    def clean_user_file(self):
        check_user_file = self.cleaned_data.get('user_file')
        if check_user_file:
            if check_user_file.size > 5120000:
                raise ValueError('File is too big for upload')
        return check_user_file

# The problem arises when I submit the instance, which saves the file from the form to upload_to=file_destination
# In file_destination I get an error on self.user.username saying || DoesNotExist at "" UserFile has no user.
# My self.user is an None object.

def file_destination(self, filename):
    filename = name_generator()
    url = "%s/%s/%s" % (self.user.username, 'uploads' ,filename)
    return url
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manually set the `user` field on your `UserFile` instance:

```
if form.is_valid():
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.user = request.user
    instanve.save()
    form.save_m2m()  # add this if you add m2m relationships to `UserFile`
```

Also, it is a good idea to redirect after the form handling succeeds:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
# ...
return redirect("view-name")
```

Comment: My model field is a ManyToOne, what will save_m2m do then?

Comment: The `save_m2m` call is there in the case you add m2m later, it is not really needed right now in your case. Just be aware that if you add m2m relationships to `UserFile`, you need to add this call!